# Add a number to each element with the same class

Tags: javascript

In order to count all elements with the same class I can write the following:

```
 var count = document.querySelectorAll('#teamMember .r-team-member').length;
 console.log(count);
```

How can I add a number to each of those elements as a class? For example, the HTML is:

```
<div id="teamMember" class="size-33">
    <div class="r-team-member">
        <div style="display:none;" id="bio"></div>
        <div id="readBio">Read Bio</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also written the following javascript:

```
function showBio() {
    document.getElementById('bio').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('readBio').style.display = "none";
}
```

Which is working, but if I click on the 'Read Bio' div, then it opens all of the Bios.

What javascript can I write than make it something along the lines of:

```
<div id="teamMember" class="size-33">
    <div class="r-team-member 1">
        <div id="bio"></div>
        <div id="readBio"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="teamMember" class="size-33">
    <div class="r-team-member 2">
        <div id="bio"></div>
        <div id="readBio"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

etc?

Comment: Element Id should be unique ...

Comment: [CSS class names should not start with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

Comment: Seems from the question that you already know how to get the element, not try changing its class